# Problema com Valgrind e alocação dinâmica em C++

Tags: c++, ponteiro, memória, alocação, valgrind

Eu tenho um programa um tanto quanto maior que esse, eu selecionei a parte que não consigo resolver, são erros que parecem infundados, eu realmente já tentei de tudo. Imagino que seja um problema estrutural.

Vou postar o código que selecionei, ele não é o programa inteiro mas carrega meu problema

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <fstream>
 #include <cstring>
 #include <cctype>
 #include <cstdio>

 using namespace std;

 struct Agregado
 {
    char *chave;
    char *media;
    double n;
  };

  int estrutura_e_ordena(ifstream &fin, int registros, int posicaoChave, int 
  posicaoMedia)
  {
    string linha;
    Agregado *reg = new Agregado[registros]();
    int indice = 0;
    int j;
    int cont = 0;
    for (indice = 0; fin.peek() != EOF; indice++)
    {
    for (j = 0; j < registros && fin.peek() != EOF; j++)
    {

        getline(fin, linha);
        int t = strlen(linha.c_str()) + 1;
        char *c = new char[t];
        strcpy(c, linha.c_str());

        reg[j].media = new char[t];
        reg[j].chave = new char[t];

        reg[j].chave = strtok(c, ", ");


        for(int i=1; i<=posicaoChave; i++){
            reg[j].chave = strtok(NULL, ", ");
        }    


        reg[j].media = strtok(c, ", ");
        for(int i=1; i<=posicaoMedia; i++){
            reg[j].media = strtok(NULL, ", ");
        }

        delete[] c;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
    {

        delete[] reg[i].media;
        delete[] reg[i].chave;
    }
    j = 0;
}

fin.close();
delete[] reg;
return indice;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

char *nome = new char[strlen(argv[1]) + 1];
strcpy(nome, argv[1]);

int registros = atoi(argv[2]);
char *chave = new char[strlen(argv[3]) + 1];
strcpy(chave, argv[3]);

char *media = new char[strlen(argv[4]) + 1];
strcpy(media, argv[4]);

ifstream fin(nome);

int posicaoChave = 0, posicaoMedia = 1;

estrutura_e_ordena(fin, registros, posicaoChave, posicaoMedia);
delete[] nome;
delete[] chave;
delete[] media;
fin.close();
return 0;
}
```

O valgrind aponta os seguintes erros`

```
==1275== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==1275==    at 0x483758B: operator delete[](void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:641)
==1275==    by 0x1095AD: estrutura_e_ordena(std::basic_ifstream<char, 
std::char_traits<char> >&, int, int, int) (saco.cpp:55)
==1275==    by 0x109755: main (saco.cpp:82)
==1275==  Address 0x4d44150 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 6 free'd
==1275==    at 0x483758B: operator delete[](void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:641)
==1275==    by 0x1094F5: estrutura_e_ordena(std::basic_ifstream<char, 
std::char_traits<char> >&, int, int, int) (saco.cpp:49)
==1275==    by 0x109755: main (saco.cpp:82)
==1275==  Block was alloc'd at
==1275==    at 0x483650F: operator new[](unsigned long) 
(vg_replace_malloc.c:423)
==1275==    by 0x109369: estrutura_e_ordena(std::basic_ifstream<char, 
std::char_traits<char> >&, int, int, int) (saco.cpp:30)
==1275==    by 0x109755: main (saco.cpp:82)`
```

Eu não tenho muita experiência com o Valgrind, mas ele me aponta erros como  "Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()" que não fazem sentido nenhum, eu apenas aloco, opero o vetor e depois desaloco. Obs: Eu estou usando exatamente o que posso usar, não posso usar string, exceto para ler a linha e copiar para o vetor de char, e não posso usar funções e bibliotecas orientadas a objetos.

Contextualizando, esse projeto é um trabalho de ordenação externa, e caso queiram testar, a entrada que estou usando é

```
A, N1
a, 0.501731038000827
b, 0.509714268041373
c, 0.501163287116723
d, 0.503026776283879
e, 0.500950413375161
f, 0.502142644681647
g, 0.501214116159229
h, 0.501854463314318
i, 0.496600248440377
j, 0.493076243330675
k, 0.504138789431106
l, 0.498207171945015
m, 0.496285022266796
n, 0.501737614492674
o, 0.500618404020615
p, 0.498576392529170
q, 0.499085967949642
r, 0.509327587184305
s, 0.500491417712932
```

Os argumentos na linha de comando são, 1 = nome da entrada, 2 = número de linhas que posso ler por vez, recomendo 6. 3 = chave de agregação, no caso A. 4 = coluna da média (N1), números que, em outra parte do projeto, servirão para tirar uma média de acordo com a chave de agregação selecionada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Começo por dizer que você complicou um bom bocado, usando `char *` em todo o lado quando `std::string` era bastante mais simples, evitando ter que gerir a memoria de cada string individualmente, assim como os seus terminadores.

O problema deve-se na verdade ao `strtok`, que faz algo diferente do que você imaginou.

Ora atente na [documentação](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/):

> ... Return Value: If a token is found, a pointer to the beginning of the token.

Ou seja o `strtok` devolve-lhe um ponteiro para o inicio da palavra(token) encontrada.
Então comecemos pela alocação de memória:

```
reg[j].chave = new char[t];
```

Nesta primeira instrução, aloca um array de chars com tamanho `t` e guarda o ponteiro para esse array em `reg[j].chave`.

Mas logo de seguida faz isto:

```
reg[j].chave = strtok(c, ", ");
```

Aqui guarda por cima do ponteiro que original, o que é valido para fazer `delete`, um ponteiro para um caratere no meio da string.

Logo mais abaixo quando faz:

```
delete[] reg[i].chave;
```

Já se torna num `delete` invalido pois já não aponta para o inicio da string, e sim para o meio/fim da mesma. O mesmo acontece para o `reg[i].media`.

Minha proposta de solução:

Naturalmente que você pode sempre guardar o ponteiro original noutra variável e fazer `delete` nesse, mas o que eu realmente lhe proponho como solução (que não irei demonstrar aqui nesta resposta devido à extensão) é reescrever tudo mas agora utilizando o apropriado de c++.

Isto significa trocar os `char*` por `std::string`, e fazer um `split` versão c++ utilizando por exemplo [find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) e [substr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr). [Tem um exemplo de `split` dessa forma no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37454181/6087092). Também existem outras alternativas como utilizar o 3º parametro do `getline` partindo de uma `stream`, ou usar um `stringstream` se for para separar por espaços.

Com essa troca todo o código que tem aqui na pergunta reduz para menos de metade, e fica bem mais simples de perceber e manter, assim como evita falhas de gestão de memoria uma vez que a string já gere a memoria dos seus carateres internamente.